# Atomic Simulation Environment (ASE) is unable to read a big trajectory file

Tags: molecular-dynamics, computational-chemistry, python, visualization-software, atomic-simulation-environment

The problem that I face is the ASE software can't read the trajectory file and throws this error `ValueError: buffer is smaller than requested size`. My assumption is that it can be ascribed to the big file size of the `nve_traj` (~500MB).

I checked that the indexing method worked previously with smaller size file. Also, I get the same error when I truly to visualise the file in the ASE-GUI.
Incase someone ask why I need to index the file, `m = traj.get_masses()` .
I would be grateful if someone can give a working solution to either the ValueError or suggest a method to get masses from the trajectory.

```
import ase.io
from ase.io.trajectory import Trajectory

traj  = ase.io.read('nve.traj', index=':', format='traj')

# to replace the some atoms e.g. H
m = traj.get_masses()
```

As suggested the whole error,

````
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [4], in <cell line: 1>()
----> 1 traj = ase.io.read('md.traj', index= "-1")

File ~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\ase\io\formats.py:736, in read(filename, index, format, parallel, do_not_split_by_at_sign, **kwargs)
    733     return list(_iread(filename, index, format, io, parallel=parallel,
    734                        **kwargs))
    735 else:
--> 736     return next(_iread(filename, slice(index, None), format, io,
    737                        parallel=parallel, **kwargs))

File ~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\ase\parallel.py:275, in parallel_generator.<locals>.new_generator(*args, **kwargs)
    269 @functools.wraps(generator)
    270 def new_generator(*args, **kwargs):
    271     if (world.size == 1 or
    272         args and getattr(args[0], 'serial', False) or
    273         not kwargs.pop('parallel', True)):
    274         # Disable:
--> 275         for result in generator(*args, **kwargs):
    276             yield result
    277         return

File ~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\ase\io\formats.py:803, in _iread(filename, index, format, io, parallel, full_output, **kwargs)
    801 # Make sure fd is closed in case loop doesn't finish:
    802 try:
--> 803     for dct in io.read(fd, *args, **kwargs):
    804         if not isinstance(dct, dict):
    805             dct = {'atoms': dct}

File ~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\ase\io\trajectory.py:406, in read_traj(fd, index)
    404 trj = TrajectoryReader(fd)
    405 for i in range(*index.indices(len(trj))):
--> 406     yield trj[i]

File ~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\ase\io\trajectory.py:259, in TrajectoryReader.__getitem__(self, i)
    257 if isinstance(i, slice):
    258     return SlicedTrajectory(self, i)
--> 259 b = self.backend[i]
    260 if 'numbers' in b:
    261     # numbers and other header info was written alongside the image:
    262     atoms = read_atoms(b, traj=self)

File ~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\ase\io\ulm.py:584, in Reader.__getitem__(self, index)
    582 def __getitem__(self, index):
    583     """Return Reader for item *index*."""
--> 584     data = self._read_data(index)
    585     return Reader(self._fd, index, data, self._little_endian)

File ~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\ase\io\ulm.py:577, in Reader._read_data(self, index)
    575 def _read_data(self, index):
    576     self._fd.seek(self._offsets[index])
--> 577     size = int(readints(self._fd, 1)[0])
    578     data = decode(self._fd.read(size).decode(), False)
    579     self._little_endian = data.pop('_little_endian', True)

File ~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\ase\io\ulm.py:187, in readints(fd, n)
    186 def readints(fd, n):
--> 187     a = np.frombuffer(fd.read(int(n * 8)), dtype=np.int64, count=n)
    188     if not np.little_endian:
    189         # Cannot use in-place byteswap because frombuffer()
    190         # returns readonly view
    191         a = a.byteswap()

ValueError: buffer is smaller than requested size```
````

Comment: What kind of trajectory is it and what software did you use to write the trajectory file?

Comment: It would help to see the whole trace of the ValueError exception.

Comment: @GeoffHutchison Please check the post now, I added the error.

Comment: @SRMaiti I use the ASE GUI for visualisation.

Comment: Hi @Saha_1994, can you try compressing your file (let's say using gzip) and read it directly to ASE? It seems ASE can now read compressed .gz files directly.

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned. It can be reopened if OP addresses questions/suggestions from the comments.